# Xamarin - unable to track referrers with Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, xamarin

I'm migration one of my app using Xamarin, and I've faced a problem with referrer tracking using Google Analytics. Google Analytics service is linked correctly with Google Play app (I'm able to track referrer with old version of my app written in Java). Google Analytics works in my app for Activities and Custom Events.

I'm using Xamarin.GooglePlayServices 22.0.0.0.

Here is a part of manifest related to Google Analytics:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

```
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: How are you testing this? Please enable verbose logging with GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE); What happens when you broadcast install referrer to your app? Is it reported?

Here is link to the guide on how to test your install campaign
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was solved in latest release of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices. At the moment the latest version of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices is 25.0.0.0, and referrer tracking works correct with the same configuration as posted in question.